# How to create dynamic routerlinks in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, router, angular2-services

I am new at angular 2 and I am trying to create a news website which means the home page for example contains different articles from different categories .

So I get the articles for example in the slider section from api the json result contains the link ex: '/slider/article1' , '/sport/article3' etc ..

when I try to loop the results in the html the routerlink doesn't work !

Here is a sample code

Home.component.html // lets say that link contains '/sport'

```
<a [routerLink]="[item.link]">{{item.title}}</a>
```

Route.config.ts

```
export const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'sport', component: SportComponent }
];
```

** I forget to mention the error

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'outlets' of
>   null

Home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeService } from '../../_services/home.service';
import { ContentInfo } from '../../_models/content';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  providers: [HomeService]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  mainNewsItem: ContentInfo[];
  constructor(private _homeService: HomeService) {
    this.mainNewsItem = [];
  }
  ngOnInit() {
        // Get Main News Item
        this._homeService.getMainNewsItem()
            .subscribe(content => this.mainNewsItem = content,
            error => this._homeService = <any>error)
            ;
  }
}
```

I used *ngif

```
*ngIf="mainNewsItem?.length > 0"
```

the div is gone but why ? I mean the mainNewsItem contains data !

Thanks :)

Comment: can you reproduce your problem on plunker ? and what is the error in the console

Comment: [According to the documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-def-with-parameter), you should use route parameters. If you don't understand, feel free to ask !

Comment: Error - Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'outlets' of null ,

Comment: I will read this now , thank you

Comment: thanks guys , the problem was in the data is not there yet when the component is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use route parameters:

`{ path: 'sport/:articleTitle', component: SportComponent },`

> Source: [Angular doc's: route with parameter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-def-with-parameter)

In your `SportComponent` you can inject the ActivatedRoute in your constructor to recieve the parameters: `constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)`

Comment: the problem starts even there is no article title I mean even if the link is '/sport' only , someone told me that the routes loadded before the html dom finished so the error "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'outlets' of null" means that .!!

Comment: I think your 'items' are not set yet when loading. You could tackle this by adding a [`*ngIf=""` directive to your parent HTML element.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html)

Comment: I updated the question with home.component.ts , I used ngif ok the error now gone but I know there is a data in the array , why it tells me that array is empty !!

Comment: Well, this is because the data is not there YET when the component is loaded. Your data is loaded asynchronously look at this like `getMainNewsItem()` is a stream of data subscribe/listen to. When the data is set/changes (`*ngIf`) you can start using it. Maybe [this](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html) will explain it better then I can.

Comment: Thanks Mike , The problem was that I return an array in the service not <Observable<ContentInfo>> . :)